# How can I match Geolife traces using TrackMatching or similar tools?

Tags: gps, gpx, tracking, map-matching

I am working on route prediction and I decide to use realistic trace of moving object, I have choose geolife dataset
it is composed of 278 users and every user has its trips presented in GPS or GPX I am not sure format in ".plt" file

```
Geolife trajectory
WGS 84
Altitude is in Feet
Reserved 3
0,2,255,My Track,0,0,2,8421376
0
39.991364,116.326605,0,223,39750.3962731481,2008-10-29,09:30:38
39.991551,116.326653,0,163,39750.3963310185,2008-10-29,09:30:43
39.991821,116.326695,0,75,39750.3963888889,2008-10-29,09:30:48
39.991771,116.326676,0,77,39750.3964467593,2008-10-29,09:30:53
39.991825,116.326657,0,77,39750.3965046296,2008-10-29,09:30:58
```

I have tested currently [trackMatching](https://mapmatching.3scale.net/) tool but I get a problem that my format isn't supported

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<restResponse>
  <error>Invalid GPX format</error>
</restResponse>
```

I have also tested Project-OSRM but it requires an OSM map which I don't have

Comment: Would you consider to put the last question in an extra one?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. That's why I removed the second question from this thread. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use TrackMatching, you hav e to convert your input files to one of their supported formats https://mapmatching.3scale.net/fileformats

> The custom CSV/Text format has the following structure:
>
> ```
> Waypoint ID, longitude, latitude, timestamp
> ```
>
> example:
>
> ```
> 44017039,5.38949431,52.187434426,"2013-03-18T07:22:38"
> 44017040,5.389658375,52.187336919,"2013-03-18T07:22:43"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the explantion, but does the trips will be seperated if I combine them. Could you advice me to the most appropiet tool for matching this dataset?    the output I want is  trip1: road2, road2,......    Trip 2 Road 1, road 3,..... and so on. thanks in advance